# Create a handle from byte array c++ winapi

Tags: c++, winapi

I have an application that takes a handle and performs some tasks.  The handle is currently being created with CreateFile.  My problem is that CreateFile takes a filepath as one of the arguments.  I am looking for a way to return a handle from a byte array because the data in I need to process is not on disk.  Does anyone know of any functions that take a byte array and return a handle or how I would go about doing this?

Comment: I don't think there's any way to create a file handle from data in memory. Perhaps you could rewrite your application to use `IStream` instead, and you can then use `SHCreateStreamOnFileEx` and `SHCreateMemStream` to create the streams.

Comment: ".. an application that takes a handle .." -- if this is a File handle, and the tasks involve file related stuff such as ReadFile or CloseFile, then you cannot solve it by simply sending a pointer to some memory. "Handle" is not a generic type; different types of handles are "for" different operations.

Comment: If the application reads the "file" sequentially, then you could [use a pipe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You have a few choices:

1. re-design your processing logic to read data from a memory pointer instead of a `HANDLE`, then you can pass your byte array as-is to your processing logic.  In case you also need to process a file, you can read the file data into a byte array, then process it accordingly.
2. re-design your processing logic to read data from an [`IStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380034(v=vs.85).aspx) interface, then you can use [`SHCreateStreamOnFileEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759866(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`SHCreateMemStream()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773831(v=vs.85).aspx), like Jonathan Potter suggested.
3. if you must read data from a `HANDLE` using [`ReadFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467(v=vs.85).aspx) or related function, you can either:

   a. write your byte array to a temp file, then read back from that file.

   b. create an anonymous pipe using [`CreatePipe()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365152(v=vs.85).aspx), then write the byte array to one end and read the data from the other end, like Harry Johnston suggested.

Comment: If he is to rewrite his code, you should specify that he could use the std::iostream since that way you can make use of the std::stringstream which I think is easier to use than rewriting properly IStream implementations.

Comment: You are assuming the input data is textual in nature, otherwise `std::stringstream` is not appropriate. But you could use `std::ifstream` for file data. There is no STL wrapper for putting a byte array into a `std::istream` (that I know of), so you might have to write a custom derived class for that case.

Comment: Well, the iostream stuff is based on some buffer implementation which is definitively binary. Anyway, if you do not know yet, you can write binary data in a string, no problem, including `'\0'`. Of course, the c_str() is not 1 to 1 compatible with such a string. Cassandra actually uses the std::string to transmit data between client and server side and those handle any type of data including numbers (i.e. you can save an integer or a floating point in a string in binary format).

Answer (score 0):

Using `CreateFile()` with the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY` attribute allows the operating system to keep the file in memory. You still have a copy happening as you have to write your memory buffer to the file, and then read that data back from that file, but if you have enough cache memory, nothing will hit the hard drive.

See for more details here:

[CREATEFILE2_EXTENDED_PARAMETERS structure | Caching Behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh449426%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#caching_behavior)

It is not impossible that you could also use file mapping where the data written to the file is forced to stay in memory, but that's a lot more complicated for probably no gain as it is not unlikely going to be slower overall.